# Single page application using grunt and tomcat

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, gruntjs

We are building single page application, using AngularJS and Spring Rest services along with spring boot. For front end build we are using grunt and for server site build maven. But we are not sure hove to build single WAR file which contains build out put from gunt and our java output.

Deployment server Tomcat.

Regards
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try using maven-grunt plugin. 
https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same setup. I am invoking grunt from maven.

From maven I invoke frontend-maven-plugin it actually downloads node binary and all node packages. And invokes grunt and bower. This essentially helps me build my project in any environment without installing node(even in Jekins server). Configure warSourceDirectory to read grunts output.